# TRIG: What is the solution set of $\frac{1}{2}\ 4^{\sin^2(x)}=2^{\sin(x)}$ with the interval $[0, 2\pi]$?

Tags: trigonometry

My brother is currently in college-level Trig and sent me this problem: (P.S. -- Sorry about the awkward formatting, the parenthesis encase **powers**, not multipliers)

> "Find all real numbers in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$"
>
> $$\frac{1}{2}\ 4^{\sin^2(x)}=2^{\sin(x)}$$
>
> The solution set is {_}

Since it's been nearly a decade since I've had to do any more trigonometry than simple Physics equations, I'm hoping somebody in Math can help. :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $ 2^{2\sin^2 x - 1} = 2^{\sin x}\Rightarrow 2\sin^2x - 1 = \sin x\Rightarrow 2\sin^2x - \sin x - 1 = 0\Rightarrow (2\sin x +1)(\sin x - 1) = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Take $\ln$ to both sides of the equation (why can we do this?), and we will get $\ln(\frac{1}{2})+\sin^2(x) \ln(4)=\sin(x) \ln(2)$. If we let $\sin(x)=y,$ we would have the equation $\ln(\frac{1}{2})+\ln(4)y^2=\ln(2)y,$ which is a quadratic equation. Solve for this equation, we will get $y_1=1,y_2=-0.5$.

If $y=1$, then $\sin(x)=1$, then $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. If $y=-0.5$, then $\sin(x)=-0.5$, then...... You can finish the rest part.